# SDRAM addressing

Tags: memory, fsb, sdram

How memory controller maps linear address given by CPU to SDRAM addressing scheme?
I guess it is something like:

0x0 - rank 1, bank0, row 0, column 0

0x8 - rank 1, bank0, row 0, column 1

.

.

.

(row 0 max)

0xn - rank 1, bank 0, row 1, column 0

0xn+8 rank 1, bank 0, row 1, column 1

.

.

.

(bank 0 max)

0xm rank 1, bank 1, row 0, column 0

0xm+8 rank 1, bank 1, row 0, column 1

etc.

Is data (word) scattered across all 8 IC-s on memory module like t[his](http://images.anandtech.com/doci/3851/DRAM%20Memory%20Topology.png)
 (i.e. when writing word to rank 1, bank 0, row 0: LSByte is written to IC0 bank 0, row 0, column 0, LSByte + 1 to IC1, bank 0, row 0, column 0 ... 
MSByte to IC7, bank 0, row 0, column 0)?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the specific module was constructed.  The total row has to be 64 bits, but that can be spread across 8x 8 bit chips, or 4x 16 bit chips, etc.  This configuration is up to the manufacturer and is not visible to the CPU.